# Terminating a uwsgi worker programmatically

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi, web.py

In my application I need to "simulate" a HTTP timeout. Simply put, in this scenario:

```
client -> myapp -> server
```

`client` makes a HTTP POST connection to `myapp` which forwards it to `server`. However, `server` does not respond due to network issues or similar problems. I am stuck with an **open TCP session** from `client` which I'll need to drop.

My application uses web.py, nginx and uwsgi.

I cannot return a custom HTTP error such as `418 I am a teapot` - it has to be a connection timeout to mirror `server`'s behaviour as closely as possible.

One hack-y solution could be (I guess) to just `time.wait()` until `client` disconnects but this would use a uwsgi thread and I have a feeling it could lead to resource starvation because a `server` timeout is likely to happen for other connections. Another approach is pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25910420/how-to-handle-graceful-shutdown-in-python-uwsgi-application) however this solution implies returning something to `client`, which is not my case.

So my question is: is there an elegant way to kill a `uwsgi` worker programmatically from python code?

So far I've found

- [`set_user_harakiri(N)`](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/PythonModule.html?highlight=uwsgi%20opt#uwsgi.set_user_harakiri) which I could combine with a `time.sleep(N+1)`. However in this scenario uwsgi detects the harakiri and tries re-spawning the worker.
- [`worker_id()`](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/PythonModule.html?highlight=uwsgi%20opt#uwsgi.worker_id) but I'm not sure how to handle it - I can't find much documentation on using it
- A suggestion to use `connection_fd()` as explained [here](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src%40k%40o%40kozmic-ci-HEAD%40tailer%40__init__.py/72/uwsgi.connection_fd/python)
- [`disconnect()`](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/PythonModule.html?highlight=uwsgi%20opt#uwsgi.disconnect) which does not seem to do anything, as the code continues and returns to `client`
- [`suspend()`](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/API.html?highlight=disconnect#uwsgi-suspend) does suspend the instance, but NGINX returns the boilerplate error page

Any other idea?

**UPDATE**

Turns out it's more complicated than that. If I just close the socket or disconnect from uwsgi the nginx web server detects a 'server error' and returns a 500 boilerplate error page. And, I do not know how to tell nginx to stop being so useful.

Comment: Just for the reference: Comcast can be used to simulate bad network connections, but not sure if it does dropping connections and timeout yet: https://github.com/tylertreat/Comcast

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa thanks, but that's not exactly my problem. I said "simulate" for clarity, but what I actually need is to drop the connection altogether just like a timed-out connection would look like. It's not for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a combination of both.

1. From the  python app, return `444`
2. Configure nginx as explained [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29344415/204634) i.e. using the `uwsgi_intercept_errors` directive.